# Where does the ? go in a conditional cast in Swift?

Tags: swift, casting, conditional-statements, option-type

Where does the optional ? symbol go in a conditional cast? What are the differences?

Here is my test code in Playground with a warning where my comment says "// warning".

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit

let int: UInt8 = 1
let data: Data = Data([int])
let record: CKRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "record_type")
record.setObject(data as __CKRecordObjCValue?, forKey: "field")
record.setObject(data as? __CKRecordObjCValue, forKey: "field") // warning
```

The warning message says:

> Conditional cast from 'Data' to '__CKRecordObjCValue' always succeeds

How does Xcode interpret each example depending on where the optional ? mark goes?

If I make the Data variable Data? instead, as in the code below, the warning changes to:

> Conditional downcast from 'Data?' to '__CKRecordObjCValue' is a bridging conversion; did you mean to use 'as'?

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit

let int: UInt8 = 1
let data: Data? = Data([int])
let record: CKRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "record_type")
record.setObject(data as __CKRecordObjCValue?, forKey: "field")
record.setObject(data as? __CKRecordObjCValue, forKey: "field")
```

What is a bridging conversion?

Comment: After the as. `blah as? String` but your error is telling you that your cast is not conditional. It will always work so there is no need for the ?

Comment: But what is the difference in meaning between the two different notations?

Comment: One is saying “try to cast this to some type but return nil if it doesn’t work”. The other says “cast this to this optional type”.

Comment: @Fogmeister Ok. Got it. I added more content above. When I make the variable data of type Data? instead of Data, I get a different warning.

Answer (score 3):

First of all please use key subscription and `CKRecordValue` (rather than ugly `__CKRecordObjCValue`).

- `as? CKRecordValue` is a conditional downcast (wrong)
- `as CKRecordValue?` is a bridge cast to an optional protocol type (right)

  ```
  let int: UInt8 = 1
  let data : Data? = Data([int])
  let record = CKRecord(recordType: "record_type")
  record["field"] = data as CKRecordValue?
  ```

In the non-optional case just bridge the type without question marks

```
let data = Data([int])
...
record["field"] = data as CKRecordValue
```

---

Note:

As `Data` conforms to `CKRecordValueProtocol` a bridge cast is redundant

```
record["field"] = data
```